# Best way to run a function iteratively on file pairs from large dataset stored on permanent Dropbox link

Tags: matlab, system, dropbox, large-data, large-files

I have a very large permanent Dropbox link which has 6 folders in it. Each folder has the following file organization (I specified the organization for Folder 1 only where - represents a folder and *represents a file and 3 lines with dots means continue same pattern, but all of the main folders and subfolders are organized the same).

- -Folder 1

  - -12390r3398

    - -20253023432

      - *A2308432.edf
      - *calibration.xlsx
      - *EventList.xlsx
      - *Stage.csv
    - -20253023789

      - *A2308449.edf
      - *calibration.xlsx
      - *EventList.xlsx
      - *Stage.csv
        .
        .
        .
    - -202530243808

      - *A23086903.edf
      - *calibration.xlsx
      - *EventList.xlsx
      - *Stage.csv
  - -12390r4490

    - -20258900023

      - *A23489001.edf
      - *calibration.xlsx
      - *EventList.xlsx
      - *Stage.csv
        .
        .
        .
    - -20258978290

      - *A23489876.edf
      - *calibration.xlsx
      - *EventList.xlsx
      - *Stage.csv
        .
        .
        .
- -Folder 2
  .
  .
  .
- -Folder 3
  .
  .
  .
- -Folder 4
  .
  .
  .
- -Folder 5
  .
  .
  .
- -Folder 6
  .
  .
  .

Now, I wrote a function that I will call `myfunction`. The inputs of `myfunction` are a .edf file and a .xlsx file. The output of `myfunction` is a 6 column array, and the number of rows depends on the input files.

I want to apply `myfunction` to all of the file pairs in each of the smallest subfolders in this Dropbox link. For example, I want to have `arr1 = myfunction('A2308432.edf', 'EventList.xlsx')` for the file pair located in subfolder '20253023432' above and then I want `arr2 = myfunction('A2308449.edf', 'EventList.xlsx')` for the file pair located in subfolder '20253023789' and so on up until the last smallest subfolder in Folder 3 (please notice that even though each subfolder contains an 'EventList.xlsx' file, that each of these Excel files are actually different despite having the same name). I cannot directly download this dropbox link, or even any of the 3/6 main folders, or even a certain subfolder of a main folder as they are too large (the entire Dropbox has about 100 GB of data).

Does anyone know how I can do this in MATLAB by calling `myfunction` on all of these file pairs directly from the Dropbox link, or if I can iteratively download file pairs from Dropbox and then run my function on the file pair and then delete the file pair before moving on to the next one? Maybe another option is to move the Dropbox folder to some AWS cloud and do it from there, but I have the same question for how to do all of this on MATLAB through data stored in AWS. If you can provide code to help, I would very much appreciate as I do not have a systems background. Thanks.

I tried downloading the data and running the function on subsets of data directly. I did this using the MATLAB `dir` command, and it worked, but there is so much data that it would be ridiculous to do this for all of it.

I also looked into Dropbox APIs for MATLAB, but kept running into errors when using these (I have a very poor systems background).

Answer (score 0):

The Dropbox API does offer functionality for listing the contents of a Dropbox shared link for a folder, as well as downloading any particular file from a folder based on the shared link for the folder.

To list the contents of the folder, you should use [/2/files/list_folder](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder)[[/continue]](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder-continue). Start by supplying the shared link for the folder in the `shared_link.url` field when calling [/2/files/list_folder](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder). When you need to list a particular subfolder, also set `path` to be the relative path of the subfolder inside the linked folder.

To download any particular file inside the folder, you should use [/2/sharing/get_shared_link_file](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-get_shared_link_file). Set `url` to the shared link for the folder and `path` to the relative path of the file inside the linked folder.

You can write your code with your custom logic as needed, calling these Dropbox API endpoints as/when needed.